# How can i pass required parameters without violating validations for other input fields

Tags: java, validation, rest, hibernate-validator, spring-rest

I have created an input passing parameter class for all parameters of an module, & wants to use different parameters for different operations

My passing parameter class have fields as

```
private Integer userId;
@Id
@Column(name = "user_email_id")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email_Id.")
@Email
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
private String userEmailId;
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
@Column(name = "user_password")
private String userPassword;
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your firstName.")
@Column(name = "firstname")
@SafeHtml()
private String firstName;
@SafeHtml()
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your lastName.")
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp = "(^[0-9]{10,12}$)", message = "Please enter your Mobile Number.")
@NumberFormat
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
private String mobileNumber;
@Column(name = "user_status")
private Integer userStatus;
@Column(name = "isdeleted")
private Integer isDeleted;
@Column(name = "createdUserId")
private Integer createdUserId;
@Column(name = "profile_picturename")
private String profilePicturename;
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

private Integer isAdmin;
```

here for registration i'm using

```
 {  
"userEmailId": "sdfdfgfgf",
"userPassword": "fdsdsdf",
"firstName": "sdfsdf",
"lastName": "sfdsdfds",
"mobileNumber": "sdfgdgdf",
"userStatus": 1,
"isDeleted": 0,
"createdUserId": 1,
"profilePictureName": "kfksdjfhksjd",
"address": "sfdsdfsd"
```

}

to pass parameters in json & for login trying to pass

```
{
"userEmailId": "f@g.cm",
"userPassword": "fdsdsdf",
"isAdmin":0
```

}

parameters , but for login i'm getting validation message of other fields as well,

can anyone tell me how can i pass only needed fields to the method without getting validation message for the fields that i'm not passing

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so sure whether it makes so much sense to just group all potential parameters into a single class, but if you are saying that you only want to validate a given subset based on a specific usecase, you need to work with validation groups. Check the Hibernate Validator online docs for this feature. You basically assign the different constraints to distinctive groups, eg `Login`. When you then call `Validator#validate` you also pass the group you want to validate. If you control validation yourself that is not a problem. If you are using some other framework which in turn integrates with Bean Validation, you will need to check there how to validation for a given group.

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to pass only required fields, then i feel you should not have @notnull for other non mandatory fields, something like this:

```
private Integer userId;
@Id
@Column(name = "user_email_id")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your email_Id.")
@Email
@NotNull(message = "Enter last name")
private String userEmailId;
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your password.")
@Column(name = "user_password")
private String userPassword;
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your firstName.")
@Column(name = "firstname")
@SafeHtml()
private String firstName;
@SafeHtml()
@NotEmpty(message = "Please enter your lastName.")
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp = "(^[0-9]{10,12}$)", message = "Please enter your Mobile Number.")
@NumberFormat
@Column(name = "mobile_number")
private String mobileNumber;
@Column(name = "user_status")
private Integer userStatus;
@Column(name = "isdeleted")
private Integer isDeleted;
@Column(name = "createdUserId")
private Integer createdUserId;
@Column(name = "profile_picturename")
private String profilePicturename;
@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

private Integer isAdmin;
```